# Integrating Tensorflow into ROS

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone. I would like to the Google's inception neural network that comes with Tensorflow in a ROS Package. However, I don't have any idea on how to do this. The build system of tensorflow is different from cmake (they use bazel). Does anyone know from where can I start this?

Thank you very much for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228940/integrating-tensorflow-into-ros/) by [ErivaldoJunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/25727/erivaldojunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From now on, you can add

```
<run_depend>python-tensorflow-pip</run_depend>
```

into your package.xml, and you're ready to use tensorflow in python (after running rosdep, of course).

If you also need the C++ API, check out the experimental catkin package: https://github.com/tradr-project/tensorflow_ros .

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ErivaldoJunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/25727/erivaldojunior/) on 2017-01-26**:
Thank you for the answer. Well, I was able to integrate ROS and Tensorflow using Python. I found a sample python code using the Inception network at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/imagenet. I modified this code for my needs and it worked great with ROS.

**Comment by [ErivaldoJunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/25727/erivaldojunior/) on 2017-01-26**:
I will take a look into your code because I still need to learn how to internet tensorflow using C++ and Catkin.